# Which is better approach to add an OS user with a given public key? Terraform vs Packer

Tags: ssh, terraform, provisioning, packer

I want to add **OS** users with a given public keys. Which be will better approach to add users with keys, should I use provisioner in **Terraform** or **Packer** to add users and keys? and why?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49314752/when-to-provision-in-packer-vs-terraform/49316639#49316639 answer your question? If not could you edit your question to explain what is different in your specific case please?

Comment: Probably Packer, but this depends a lot on the details, such as the variation in your AMIs and your servers.